# Was there a Hazor for Jabin to rule over?

Tags: exodus, judges, joshua, solomon

The late-Exodus theory places the Exodus sometime during Ramesses II's reign(c. 1290-1224). This theory identifies the archaeological 1230 BC destruction of Hazor with Joshua's attack on the site. It appears, however, that Hazor wasn't rebuilt until Solomon's day. If Joshua destroyed the city in the 13th century and it wasn't rebuilt for another 2 centuries, then where was Jabin of the Deborah story ruling from?

Comment: A.O. - welcome to the site. It's an interesting question but will probably receive objections because it does not refer to specific biblical verses. You may avoid having your question closed or migrated by having it focus on specific verses from Joshua and Judges, mentioning these verses in the title.  Take the [tour](https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/help) for more info

Comment: There is no rule to include a bible verse in the Q, that rule is a recent misconception.

Answer (score 0):

The OP refers to the story of Deborah, which begins thus:

> Then the sons of Israel again did evil in the sight of the Lord, after
> Ehud died. So the Lord sold them into the hand of Jabin king of
> Canaan, who reigned in Hazor; and the commander of his army was
> Sisera, who lived in Harosheth-hagoyim. (Judes 4:1-2)

This indicates that Jabin reigned in Hazor at a time just after Joshua had conquered and destroyed it (Joshua 11).

> Joshua captured all the cities of these kings, and all their kings;
> and he struck them with the edge of the sword and utterly destroyed
> them, just as Moses the servant of the Lord had commanded. However,
> Israel did not burn any cities that stood on their mounds, except
> Hazor alone, which Joshua burned. And all the spoils of these
> cities and the cattle, the sons of Israel took as their plunder; but
> they struck every person with the edge of the sword, until they had
> destroyed them. They left no one breathing.

In addition to the seeming contradiction between this account and Judges 4, the OP mentions archaeological evidence against the Joshua account. How can readers deal with this problem?

Source critics, many quite orthodox theologically, tend to see the Book of Joshua as something other than historically factual in certain respects. In this view, the book was written long after the time in question and its purpose should be understood in the context of a later era. For example the introduction to the NASB version of Book of Joshua, published by the US Council of Catholic Bishops states:

> The fall of the Northern Kingdom in 722/721 B.C. shows its influence
> throughout. As addressed to the needs of a late preexilic audience,
> then, the book should be read not so much as imparting information
> about how Israel took over the land of Canaan, many centuries before
> the composition of the book, as teaching a lesson about how Israel is
> to avoid losing the land.

**If so, readers need not understand Joshua's utter destruction of Hazor as historical, and therefore there was indeed a Hazor for Jabin to rule over. Moreover, the entire Book of Joshua may be seen as an encouragement to the leadership of God's people at the time of King Josiah. The message of the book would thus be, as the USCCB writers imply: Judah must absolutely destroy idolatry in order to avoid the fate of the northern kingdom.**

Comment: Even if Joshua didn't do it, someone destroyed Hazor in 1230 BC, leaving it waste until Solomon's day, creating a problem for the Deborah-Barak account.

Comment: I admit this. The archaeological evidence shows one thing, the biblical account another. I am content to live with the cognitive dissonance that this creates.